# Popping elements from array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Consider an array which we know will have integers from 0 to n in sequence, starting at 0. For example:

```
a=[0,1,2]
```

Now, we pop the element at position 1.

```
a.pop(1)
```

The array we are left with:

```
[0,2]
```

And we have a[0]=0, a[1]=2.
Let's pop the element at position 0.

```
a.pop(0)
```

We are left with:

```
[2]
```

Now, referencing a[0] will yield 2.

This is the behavior I want, except that the pop operations are O(n) in time since the entire array needs to be copied over to the left. Is there a way to do this more efficiently so that each pop (or equivalent) operation is no more than O(log(n))? It's okay to take another O(n) of space if required.

After the sequence of operations shown above, querying for index 0 in the end should still return 2. I tried storing the popped elements in a binary search tree (without actually popping), but the logic became too convoluted.

Comment: This is a *list* not an array. You could use a `collections.deque` which provides efficient pop/insert at both ends

Comment: Also in the middle? The array could be very large and most pops could be happening in the center.

Comment: No, not in the middle. I read `pop(0)` both times. My mistake

Comment: `list` is based on `array`, it gives you `O(1)` access time, while you need `O(n)` time to pop an element if you want to pop anyway. If you have a tree, let's say RB-tree, it is possible to pop an element with `O(log(n))` time, but you also need `O(log(n))` time to access an element. So here is the tradeoff. If you want `O(1)` access time, I believe it is impossible to have `O(log(n))` pop time.

Comment: @Sraw "`list` is based on `array`" is about as true as "Python is based on computer". You'll have to be a lot more specific about what that stament is supposed to mean if you want it to be taken seriously.

Comment: Have you considered modifying your actual indices to account for the prior removals?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I mean the `list` in Python. Well, I am confused, we are talking about Python, right?

Comment: @Sraw. `array` is also a python thing too

Comment: Try Stack-based heap trees

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking for an alternative data structure. Linked lists are good at insertion and deletion from an arbitrary position, but you need to have a reference to the location where you want to insert or delete; otherwise, you'll be spending O(n) scanning to the location that you want to insert or delete from.

As far as I know, there is no linked list in Python's standard library, but you could implement your own.

At the end of the day, you can't do "the exact same thing" in less time; something has to give. You need to relax one of your requirements (e.g. that the list type be used).

An alternative requirement you might be able to relax is "the existing elements need to remain in the same order". If you don't mind a little re-ordering, you can swap lst[i] with lst[-1]. Then, pop from the end (which is efficient for lists). This can be done pretty easily using Python's tuple assignment. Like so:

```
lst[i], lst[-1] = lst[-1], lst[i]  # swap
lst.pop()  # Now, the item that you wanted removed is gone,
           # but the remaining elements are not
           # all in the same order as before,
           # but they mostly are.
```

This is often a viable alternative, because you don't always care about the order of a list.

Comment: Thanks. In this application, the order is important. I was hoping the use of extra O(n) space would be the thing that "gave". Also, the input is always 0,1,2,..n. I was hoping this too could be used to our advantage.

Comment: re 0, 1, 2, ... n: Um. As soon as you pop an element, you no longer have the property of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Right but we always start with consecutive numbers as opposed to any possible array. That information can't be used to our advantage?

Comment: I see. You should put that in your question then. Yes, I think that fact can be exploited: instead of maintaining a list of what has not been popped yet, keep an ordered tree (such as a self-balancing binary tree) of what HAS been popped. Then, when you want to iterate over what's left, you can iterate over range(n+1) "in parallel" with the elements of the tree, which you then use to filter out elements of range(n+1) that are in the tree.

Comment: I thought the first line indicated that. Just edited it to clarify this further. I had the same idea with the binary tree and tried to implement it here: https://github.com/ryu577/algorithms/blob/master/algorith/sequencegen/next_permutation.py" but ran into some complexity where it was no longer apparent the binary tree was helping. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, so was hoping to get some details of this approach hashed out by fresher and better minds.

Comment: Extrapolating from one data point is... fraught with danger. Explicit is better than implicit. --Zen of Python